# java.util.Scanner is not reading my file on desktop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want a scanner to read a file on my desktop. It's not in any folders, so this is what I have now as the file path. My program gives me a FileNotFoundException whenever I run it. I'm not very experienced with this, so I know whatever's wrong is something stupid. The file is called "md2016.txt".

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(
            "C:\\Users\\Romil\\Desktop\\md2016.txt"));
```

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.  Double check that the file exists in that location and that you have access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to discover the problem:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Romil\\Desktop\\md2016.txt");
System.out.println("fileExists = " + file.exists());
System.out.println("canRead = " + file.canRead());
```

If fileExists is false, it is probably a typo in the file path.

Else, if canRead is false, file does exist but for some reason is inaccessible.